# Click one cell and change all cells of the same color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a calendar where some days (each separate cells) have green, blue and others red backgrounds

I would like to be able to click one cell in the given range (one day in the calendar). If that cell has a specific background color, I would like all other cells in that range that are the same color to change and the text to be bold.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets").Range("N11:AW20")

    For Each cell In Rng

    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then
        Target.Font.Bold = True
    End If

    Exit For

    Next cell

End Sub
```

So far the text of the Target cell changes to bold but not the rest of the cells in that range.

How can I get excel to scan the rest of the range and apply the changes?

PS: Originally I would have preferred triggering the macro when hovering over the cells but I couldn't find anything to do so.

Here is the file with the calendar to give you a better idea of the whole thing.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17tveiFHu4nlw47jqmXixIQoe6j7iOTe-/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put this code into the module for the sheet with the calendar, it should activate each cell in the calendar range that has the same background color as the current selection.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCalendar As Range
    Set rngCalendar = Range("N11:AW20")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngCalendar) Is Nothing Then

        SpeedUp True

        rngCalendar.Font.Bold = False

        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In rngCalendar
            If cel.Interior.ColorIndex = Target.Interior.ColorIndex Then
                cel.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next cel

        SpeedUp False

    End If

End Sub

Private Function SpeedUp(ByVal toggleOn As Boolean)

    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(toggleOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .ScreenUpdating = Not toggleOn
        .EnableEvents = Not toggleOn
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Amazing, this does the trick! Thanks a bunch!

Is it normal that it takes so long to scan everything or is it my computer that is slow?

Comment: Likely not your computer considering how many cells it has to change. Let's see if turning off the common stuff speeds it up

Comment: Excel is updating in real time your worksheet. Maybe it will speed up things if you try disabling that behavior before the for..next statement with Application.ScreenUpdating = false and re-enabling it after the for... next statement with Application.ScreenUpdating = true

Comment: @MikeRophone let me know if that change helps. I just made a mockup excel file of the same size as your listed range and even before I added my `SpeedUp` function the change was pretty instant so I can't really tell whether there was a change

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your loop doesn't actually do anything to the cell it's in.

You could change it into something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True

Dim cell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets").Range("N11:AW20")

    If target.Interior.Colorindex = 37 then

     For Each cell In Rng

         If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then
           cell.Font.Bold = True
         End If

    Next cell

    End if

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I've tried that too, but it would only make the target cell bold..

Comment: That's odd, it works for me using your calendar. Are you sure you tried it without the 'exit for'-statement you had? Because that ensures that you only go through the loop once.

Comment: You're right it does work! I must have missed something when copy-pasting

Answer (score 0):

I think it should help :)

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim status As Integer
Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets").Range("N11:AW20")

For Each cell In Rng
    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then
        Target.Font.Bold = True
        status = 1
        Exit For
    End If

Next cell
If status = 1 Then
    Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    Rng.Font.Bold = True
End If
```

Comment: Okay we're getting closer, but everything in the range turns blue and bold now :/

Comment: Yes, thats what I though You want to be... so what should be blue and bold when it detect color 37 in specified range?

Comment: I was looking to highlight only the cells that are the same color :)
Thanks a bunch though, the next answers fixed my problem